# Identify multiple correlations between two signals

Tags: python, signal-processing, cross-correlation

I have two time signals each containing the two same pulses but at different position.

picture describing the two signals:

[image: picture describing the two signals]

How can I get with python the time shifts between the two signals for each pulse?
Cross correlation does not seem a robust way to do the job... 
you can see there the cross correlation function and the two time shifts I would like to recover:

[image: the cross correlation function and the two time shifts I would like to recover]

Although the time shift is perfectly obtained from the maximum of the cross correlation function if we have only one pulse you can see that it does not help much in the case of multiple pulses.

This is my test program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

N = 200     # Number of points in initial, unshifted signals
N_pad = 500 # Total number of points at the end
t = np.linspace(-1, 1, N) # Dummy time vector
dt = t[1]-t[0] # Time step
Fs = 1.0/dt    # Sampling frequency
pulse1 = signal.gausspulse(t, fc=5) # Create a pulse at 5 Hz
pulse2 = signal.gausspulse(t, fc=8) # Create a pulse at 8 Hz

# Shift and pad the pulses
pulse1_shifted = np.concatenate((pulse1,np.zeros(50)), axis=0)
pulse2_shifted = np.concatenate((pulse2,np.zeros(100)), axis=0)
pulse1_shifted_padded = np.concatenate((np.zeros(N_pad-len(pulse1_shifted)),pulse1_shifted), axis=0)
pulse2_shifted_padded = np.concatenate((np.zeros(N_pad-len(pulse2_shifted)),pulse2_shifted), axis=0)

# Create signal 1 as the sum of the two pulses
sig1 = pulse1_shifted_padded + pulse2_shifted_padded

# Different time shift
pulse1_shifted = np.concatenate((pulse1,np.zeros(60)), axis=0)
pulse2_shifted = np.concatenate((pulse2,np.zeros(150)), axis=0)
pulse1_shifted_padded = np.concatenate((np.zeros(N_pad-len(pulse1_shifted)),pulse1_shifted), axis=0)
pulse2_shifted_padded = np.concatenate((np.zeros(N_pad-len(pulse2_shifted)),pulse2_shifted), axis=0)

# Create signal 2 as the sum of the two pulses
sig2 = pulse1_shifted_padded + pulse2_shifted_padded

# Create new time vector at the same sampling rate
t = np.arange(dt*N_pad,step=dt)

# Plot the two signals
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,sig1,label="Signal 1")
plt.plot(t,sig2,label="Signal 2")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.title("The two signals. Orange and blue has been recorded at 100 m distance")

# Plot the cross correlation between the two signals
corr = signal.correlate(sig1,sig2)
dt = np.arange(1-N_pad,N_pad)/Fs # Time shift vector
plt.figure()
plt.plot(dt,corr)
plt.plot([0.1,0.1],[-20,20],"--")
plt.plot([0.5,0.5],[-20,20],"--")
plt.ylim([-15,15])
plt.xlabel("Time shift (s)")
plt.ylabel("Cross correlation function")
```

Do you have a work around?

Thank you so much

Comment: if the pulses have different frequency base component as in your example then they are probably more easily seperated by FFT

Answer (score 0):

Since cross-correlation works perfectly with two pulses, you could choose any pulse to be a baseline and perform pairwise cross-correlations with the rest to determine the offsets as a quick workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an automated method to extract the time shift between the orange and green cursors in cross-correlation responses such as the one you provided in your question.  This time shift would be the marginal time shift between the two pulse pairs in your example.  The marginal time shift between two pulse pairs such as those in your example can be inferred directly from cross-correlation results such as the results you provided. You can do this by first detecting the local maxima points in the cross-correlation results.  Next, sort the local maxima points in descending order by amplitude, while retaining the time stamp associated with each local maximum.  The marginal shift between the two pulses will then be equal to the difference between the two time stamps associated with the top two local maxima points in the sorted list of local maxima.